# Different outputs when using <%= %>

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

To get fully qualified path of application I have wrote a function:

```
    public class Generic
    {
        public static string FullyQualifiedApplicationPath
        {
            get
            {
                //Return variable declaration
                string appPath = string.Empty;

                //Getting the current context of HTTP request
                var context = HttpContext.Current;

                //Checking the current context content
                if (context != null)
                {
                    //Formatting the fully qualified website url/name
                    appPath = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
                                            context.Request.Url.Scheme,
                                            context.Request.Url.Host,
                                            context.Request.Url.Port == 80
                                                ? string.Empty
                                                : ":" + context.Request.Url.Port,
                                            context.Request.ApplicationPath);
                }

                if (appPath.EndsWith("/"))
                    appPath = appPath.Substring(0, appPath.Length - 1);

                return appPath;
            }
        }

    }
```

when I use it in `<head>` tag between `<%=%>` I am getting different outputs.

```
<link href="<%= Generic.FullyQualifiedApplicationPath %>/Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<%= Generic.FullyQualifiedApplicationPath %>/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

html output:

```
<link href="&lt;%= Generic.FullyQualifiedApplicationPath %>/Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://localhost:2093/SourceOne/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

just wandering why asp.net engine sends `&lt;%= Generic.FullyQualifiedApplicationPath %>` to client.

--NJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET basically treated your inline evaluation as string literal and escaped it.  You may try using Databinding syntax <%# %>

```
<link runat="server" id="lnkStyle" href='<%# Generic.FullyQualifiedApplicationPath   + "/Styles/StyleSheet.css"%>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script runat="server" id="scptJQuery" src='<%# Generic.FullyQualifiedApplicationPath + "/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then in your code behind, override OnPreRender, and put in the following logic

```
lnkStyle.DataBind();
scptJQuery.DataBind();
```

It is important that the binding syntax is not mixed with other literals, or ASP.NET would treat the whole attribute as string literal.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in head tag Link consider as server control and in server controls hreaf automatically decoded.

you can check add runat attribute on `a` tag

```
<a runat="server" href='<%= Generic.FullyQualifiedApplicationPath %>/Styles/StyleSheet.css'></a>
```

output will be

```
<a href="&lt;%= Generic.FullyQualifiedApplicationPath %>/Styles/StyleSheet.css" ></a>
```

I think solution is pass href from code behind

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" id="mystyle" />
```

in code behind

```
mystyle.Href= Generic.FullyQualifiedApplicationPath + "/Styles/StyleSheet.css";
```

Comment: Anytime when you mix <%= %> with string literal in an attribute. ASP.NET would treat the whole attribute as string literal and escape the whole string.  While assigning it in code behind is a solution, I generally find using Databinding syntax is a cleaner design-logic separation.

Comment: yeah your solution is looking much cleaner, thanks for this better solution. :)